# Merge into master why does datetime stamp show original commit time rather than merge time?

Tags: git

If I merge a branch into master, and then view the history in /master what should I see?
The time of the commit that was done in the branch or the time that the merge was done and commited to master?
I just did that and the date/time I see in AzureDevops is not today, but rather something different.
Is is that by design?

[Edit] 
Here are the steps I did, manually through the Git commandline

```
 git checkout master
 git merge my-branch-name
 git push origin master
```

[ Update ]
I think I get it now, just trying to figure out why.  Turns out this was actually a fast-forward merge.  I have seen sort of thing mentioned before, but if one really needs master to reflect the time it was changed, then there is a flag for NOT doing a fast-foward merge.  That should tag the master branch with the date/time of when the commit happens?

```
git merge --no-ff <branch>
```

Comment: Did you do a fast forward merge? If you did a fast forward merge, then the branch pointer is just moved to the existing commit. If you forced a new merge commit or if a merge commit had to take place, then it would create a new commit. This is Git behavior and has nothing to do with Azure DevOps.

Comment: @Daniel Mann, I second this. Unless you do a `force` merge or make a new merge commit, the time stamp would be the original one.